# Prettier not formatting CSS code in React

Tags: css, reactjs, formatting, prettier

I'm trying to format the css using Prettier but its not working. Is there a part of setting that I'm missing out. Any help would be appreciated.

following is the setting.json file.

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "scm.inputFontFamily": "",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Lig, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
    "html.format.endWithNewline": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.eslint": true }, 
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true, 
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true
}
```